# sql set the week number start

Tags: sql, date, week-number

This statement gives me the number of the `current week` starting from the `1st of january`

```
select datepart(week,getdate())
```

I would like the calculation to be done starting from `1st november`. 

Is there a way I can accomplish this? 
I know the date first method can pick the day the week starts etc.

Comment: Please tag your `RDBMS`

Comment: please tag DBMS and show input and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may looking for [`DateDiff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
select DATEDIFF(week, '1-Nov-2014', GETDATE()) + 1
OutPut: 45
```